# Why is craft adding a rel attribute with inline styles in my textarea?

Tags: redactor, richtext

It looks like redactor is adding a rel attribute to images as they are added to content via the RTE. Removing the rel attribute and then switching views adds it back in again.

How can I remove the rel attribute as it's affecting validation: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fgrowthwise.com.au%2Fnews%2F2015%2Fgetting-organised-for-tax-sucks-is-there-an-easier-way

[image: WYSIWYG View]

[image: Source View]

Comment: Might be a redactor bug, looking at the log, they had thought to fix it in v10.1 : http://d.pr/i/u5fo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this was a Redactor bug they fixed back in [10.1](http://imperavi.com/redactor/log).

The latest version of Craft ([2.4.2684](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2684)) is currently running Redactor 10.2.2, so make sure you're Craft installation is up-to-date.